# Collapse split windows

Tags: window-splitting

Given split windows like this:

```
|------|-------|
|1     |2      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
|3     |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

There are two options to collaps the split windows:

- delete-other-windows (Ctrl-x 1)
- delete-window (Ctrl-x 0)

**Question**: is there a way to control how they collapse?

---

For example, how can I collapse like this:

```
|------|-------|
|1             |
|              |
|------|-------|
|3     |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

, this:

```
|------|-------|
|2             |
|              |
|------|-------|
|3     |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

, this:

```
|------|-------|
|1     |2      |
|      |       |
|      |-------|
|      |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

, or this:

```
|------|-------|
|3     |2      |
|      |       |
|      |-------|
|      |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [ace-window](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window).

If you bind it like this:

```
(global-set-key "M-p" 'ace-window)
```

You can switch to window 2 by pressing <kbd>M-p 2</kbd>.  Also, you
can delete window 2 by pressing <kbd>M-p x2</kbd>: this will bring you
into your first example.  Other examples follow by just changing the
final key.

There are other modifiers present:

- Use <kbd>x</kbd> to delete
- Use <kbd>m</kbd> to swap
- Use <kbd>v</kbd> to split vertically
- Use <kbd>b</kbd> to split horizontally
- Use <kbd>i</kbd> to delete other windows than the selected one
- Use <kbd>o</kbd> to delete other windows than the current one
- Use <kbd>n</kbd> to switch to the last window

The last two modifiers actually require no further input, while the
others always prompt you for a window to act upon.

The modifiers are customizable via `aw-dispatch-alist`.
The window keys (which are 1/2/3/4... by default) are customizable via `aw-keys`.

Here's the setting that I'm using:

```
(setq aw-keys '(?a ?s ?d ?f ?g ?h ?j ?k ?l))
```

Answer (score 10):

The function `delete-window` has an optional argument WINDOW.

The function `window-in-direction` has a mandatory argument of DIRECTION and optional arguments for WINDOW IGNORE SIGN WRAP MIN.  To learn more about these arguments by reading the doc-string, a user may type `M-x describe-function RET window-in-direction RET`.

For example, the following four functions could be used to control the direction a window is deleted.  A user may wish to assign keyboard shortcuts.

```lisp
(defun delete-window-above ()
"Delete window in direction 'above."
(interactive)
  (delete-window (window-in-direction 'above)))

(defun delete-window-below ()
"Delete window in direction 'below."
(interactive)
  (delete-window (window-in-direction 'below)))

(defun delete-window-left ()
"Delete window in direction 'left."
(interactive)
  (delete-window (window-in-direction 'left)))

(defun delete-window-right ()
"Delete window in direction 'right."
(interactive)
  (delete-window (window-in-direction 'right)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just focus on the window you'd want to delete and `C-x 0`

I know its a dated post but might be useful to someone.