# How to control the direction of collapse with `C-x 0` or `delete-window`?

Tags: window-splitting

This is a follow up to this [emacs stackexchange question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/14347/15780):

Given split windows like this:

```
|------|-------|
|1     |2      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
|3     |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

With `C-x 0` (or the command `delete-window`) we can delete a window. For example, with `point` on window-1 if we execute `C-x 0` then window-1 will be deleted. But how to control the *direction* of collapse i.e. - how to pick between the following *two* possible ways of deleting window-1:

```
|------|-------|
|2             |
|              |
|------|-------|
|3     |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

Or,

```
|------|-------|
|3     |2      |
|      |       |
|      |-------|
|      |4      |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate question. Please search with `[window-splitting]` to see. If so, please delete this one.

Comment: @Drew: Thanks for the alert. I checked - there are 149 questions right now with the tag `[window-splitting]`. I could not find an answer to this question in any of those. Please let me know if I overlooked and I will delete this post. Thanks again!

Comment: There is one solution that I can think of: suppose you end up with one of the layouts but you wanted the other - then swap window-2 and window-3 and then transpose the layout to go to the other layout. But this may not be always possible if there are more than 4 windows. But I imagine some other sequence of window layout transformations may transition between both the layouts. However, it will be nice if all that _extra work_ can be avoided by being able to chose the direction of collapse while deleting window!

Comment: Thanks for checking! Sorry I was mistaken that this might be a dup.